# Nested filter numerical range

Tags: json, elasticsearch, lucene

I have the following json object:

```
{
  "Title": "Terminator,
  "Purchases": [
     {"Country": "US", "Site": "iTunes", "Price": 4.99},
     {"Country": "FR", "Site": "Google", "Price": 5.99}
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to find an object specifying a Country+Site+PriceRange. For example, the above should return True on `Country=US&Price<5.00`, but should return False on `Country=FR&Price<5.00`. How would the index and query look to do this? Here is another answer that this is a follow-up question to: [Search within array object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469630/search-within-array-object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a Range query to your Bool query logic tree. This will return documents that match US for country and have the Price field with a numeric value less than 5.

```
{ "query": 
    { "nested" : {
            "path" : "Purchases",
            "score_mode" : "avg",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "match" : {"Purchases.Country" : "US"}
                        },
                        {
                            "range" :  "Purchases.Price":
                            {
                                "lte": 5
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```